# Negative random number in Swift

Tags: swift

I am developing an iPhone app in swift and there's a requirement where I want to generate **NEGATIVE** random numbers always.

I know the way to generate random numbers but don't seem to figure out a way to generate **negative numbers only**.

Comment: Can you multiply your result by `-1`?

Comment: What *range* do you want, and what *distribution*? What does the generator you're using return?

Comment: there are lots of makeshift ways like multiplying with -1, though I wanted to know if there's some concrete way defined in Swift.

Comment: @BathSheba: Currently I am using a makeshift way to convert the unsigned random number generated to a signed one.

Comment: What's wrong with the "makeshift" ways?  Is it a code brevity thing or a randomness "quality" issue to you?

Comment: wouldn't you like to know how swift handles this situation? And yes, "quality" is a priority. That's why i wanted a way coming straight from Apple.

Answer (score 12):

Please try to use this one

```
let lowerValue = -100
let upperValue = 0
let result = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(upperValue - lowerValue + 1))) +   lowerValue

print(result)

Output
```

**-81**

Comment: Thanks for your answer, though I was looking for a concrete way defined in swift. It's strange that there's no option to implement it in Swift.

Comment: @TaranGoel It is implemented in Swift.

Comment: @vacawama Thanks a lot, I've your last solution.

Comment: The beauty of my last suggestion is that it works for positive and negative numbers.  There is no treating them differently, and `let lowerValue = -100; let upperValue = 0` is more explicit that you are asking for negative numbers.  Note also that `Int` is inferred by `Swift`, so `let lowerValue = -100` is sufficient.

Comment: @vacawama Done according to your suggestion. Anyways thanks a lot for your beautiful answer.

Comment: You're welcome.  One last thing, please lose the semicolons! ;-)

Comment: Hahahha i removed all semicolons.

Comment: thanks! for your wonderful answer. By implemented in Swift i meant an OOTB function to generate negative random numbers. Though your solution works just fine.

Comment: you saved me today!

Answer (score 5):

This is your function, I believe:

```
extension Int {

/// Generates a random `Int` within `0...100`
public static func random() -> Int {
    return random(0...100)
}

/// Generates a random `Int` inside of the closed interval.
public static func random(interval: ClosedInterval<Int>) -> Int {
    return interval.start + Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(interval.end - interval.start + 1)))
}

}
```

Usage example:

```
Int.random(-10...0)
```

It is taken from [RandomKit](https://github.com/nvzqz/RandomKit) library - it looks very useful for various purposes.

Answer (score 4):

```
var randomNumber = -1 * Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(5)))
```

5 will make sure that the random number is generated though zero to five.

Answer (score 2):

---

### #1. `Int`'s `random(in:)` method

With Swift 5, `Int` has a type method called [`random(in:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/int/2995648-random). `random(in:)` has the following declaration:

```
static func random(in range: Range<Int>) -> Int
```

> Returns a random value within the specified range.

The following Playground sample code shows how to use `random(in:)` with a range of negative integers in order to get a negative random number from them:

```
let range = -70 ..< -50
let randomNumber = Int.random(in: range)
print(randomNumber) // prints: -57
```

```
let closedRange = Int.min ..< 0
let randomNumber = Int.random(in: closedRange)
print(randomNumber) // prints: -7618449904516816385
```

`Int` also has a type method called [`random(in:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/int/2995646-random) that accepts a parameter of type `ClosedRange<Int>`:

```
let closedRange = -70 ... -50
let randomNumber = Int.random(in: closedRange)
print(randomNumber) // prints: -66
```

---

### #2. `Int`'s `random(in:using:)` method

If needed, you can use [`random(in:using:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/int/3020586-random) to return a random value within the specified range using a custom generator as a source for randomness. `random(in:using:)` has the following declaration:

```
static func random<T>(in range: Range<Int>, using generator: inout T) -> Int where T : RandomNumberGenerator
```

> Returns a random value within the specified range, using the given generator as a source for randomness.

Usage:

```
let range = -70 ..< -50
var randomNumberGenerator = SystemRandomNumberGenerator() // replace with custom generator
let randomNumber = Int.random(in: range, using: &randomNumberGenerator)
print(randomNumber) // prints: -52
```

Note that `random(in:using:)` has an equivalent [`random(in:using:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/int/3020584-random) that accepts a closed range as its parameter:

```
let range = -70 ... -50
var randomNumberGenerator = SystemRandomNumberGenerator() // replace with custom generator
let randomNumber = Int.random(in: range, using: &randomNumberGenerator)
print(randomNumber) // prints: -58
```

---

### #3. `Range`'s `randomElement()` and `randomElement(using:)` methods

`Range` and `ClosedRange` get [`randomElement()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/range/2996651-randomelement) and [`randomElement(using:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/range/2996654-randomelement) methods by conforming to `Collection` protocol. `randomElement()` has the following declaration:

```
func randomElement() -> Bound?
```

> Returns a random element of the collection.

You may call `randomElement()` to select a random element from a range or a closed range. This example picks a number at random from a range of negative numbers:

```
let range = -70 ..< -50
let randomNumber = range.randomElement()
print(randomNumber) // prints: Optional(-64)
```

Answer (score 1):

With **Swift 4.2**, this has been made simpler with the new random methods such as [`Int.random`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/int/2995648-random). You can read more details about the changes [here](https://learningswift.brightdigit.com/swift-4-2-random-changes-wwdc-2018/).

Comment: More specifically `Int.random(in: -70 ... -50)`